# What is the opposite of the root directory in a path?

Tags: filesystems, file-management

What do you call the opposite of the root directory in a file path, for instance:

```
/home/stephenm/somedir/
```

How would you refer to the directory

> /somedir/

in a generic way and it is not the PWD does it have a certain name?

Comment: The term root is loosely based on a tree metaphor. As such, I would consider each subdirectory to be a "branch" (and a file to be a "leaf")...though the metaphor rather breaks down in the event of symbolic links!

Comment: Thanks @GrahamWager I guess the question is, if you snap a branch off what’s the leaf at the thin end called?

Comment: I'd say they're all just branches until you hit a leaf. I'm not even sure there's an "official" thing to call it, other than just a directory or if active the *current directory*...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last segment of a path is usually called the `tail`.  The earliest use of the term that I know of was by Bill Joy in  [An Introduction to the C shell](http://www.kitebird.com/csh-tcsh-book/csh-intro.pdf), page USD4:28, where he described the C shell's `:t` tail operator.

Comment: Thanks this seems the most correct to me, I will see how the votes are later and accept "the winner" as judged by the people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a well-known and unambiguous single-word for that.

- You can call it the local name of the file's directory.
- You can call it the [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/basename.html) of the directory path.
- You could argue that a directory is never more than a single element of a path and therefore it is the **local directory**
- You could adopt the idea mentioned in Graham's comment and call it a **leaf directory**

Whatever you do is likely to need some accompanying explanation or example.

Comment: Seems to me that just calling it a "subdirectory" would suffice.